# Where to find logs about migrations errors

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, database-migration

Let's suppose we're deploying a Laravel application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
Let's suppose an error occur while migrating the database. By the way, the migrate command is put in .config file in .ebextensions folder like this :

```
container_commands:
01migrations:
    command: "php artisan migrate"
```

My question is where to find the logs related to the error ? I downloaded all the logs but I don't find anything talking about any error while migrating !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found it. It's on the EC2 instance. The log file is :

```
/var/logs/cfn-init.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a stack trace of errors by using the `vvv` flag:

```
php artisan migrate -vvv
```

You can also use `migrate:status`:

```
php artisan migrate:status
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm looking for is the right place to find logs because I'm learning AWS elastic beanstalk and finding logs to fix errors is so important to know !